# Application causing phone to heat up

Tags: android

I have been getting complaints from a few users that once they installed my application there phone has been heating up (sometimes even when the application is not running).

- What are the reasons this could be happening?
- What can I do to overcome this issue?
- Is there any way my application could heat up the phone even when it is not running?

Edit : How does a white application background compare to a black or darker application background in terms of battery usage? (assuming that excessive battery usage could heat up the phone)

Edit : Say I have a service that runs indefinitely, but does cpu specific work very rarely, how costly, in terms of cpu / battery / memory, is maintaining the service? (I know a better way would be to implement it using alarm manager, but before I change the implementation I need to know how big a difference it would make.)

Comment: If it's not running (neither in background), HOW can your app create such issues?

Comment: I am just asking. I didn't think it could.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your application this is just not going to be answerable. Have you canvassed users who report this to find out if this is model specific? We need a lot more information before this can be sensibly answered without protracted rounds of comments and clarification.

Comment: @Kev All I wanted to know was what usually heats up the phone. Other than huge computations if there was any Android specific things I need to know which can prevent heating up. Like, in one of the videos I found out that transferring data over the Internet takes up the most battery in mobile phones. I was concerned that there might be other such points which I, as an amateur might be missing. I don't see why people would need to know about my application to answer that.

Comment: Well you're effectively asking for a list of all the things that might make your app warm up a handset. That could go on forever.

Comment: Does that mean that stackoverflow does not entertain questions which can take a long time to answer?
Well, I still need an answer to it. Anyway since you closed it I guess I'll have to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing first there is no way your application can heat up the phone when your app is not running (at least in background). Now when your app is running, there are many reasons for your app to heat up the phone,

1. Calculations- especially floating point calculations.This cause lot
   of heat
2. heavy or unending loops
3. downloading large files (in background or foreground). When you
   download there are lot of network activities happening.
4. Animation and graphics, simply because it uses a lot of calculations
   in background

As a programmer, I don't thing you can do anything if someone say your app is causing phone heat up even when it is not running. So forget about it. Heat is not a thing which vanish quickly, and will remain for sometime even if the app that emitted it gets killed. I think your users misunderstood that your app emitting heat even if it is not running. You only need to make sure your app is light weight and less taxing on the processor when it is running.

Comment: Just a little note, this is and android question, not an iOS question but your points seem to be general and not aimed at any specific platform so no biggy.

Also, "complaints from a few users" means that it is most likely something to do with the app. I'm not sure what it is myself, but it is most likely a problem with the app if a few users are reporting the same issue after installing it. Forgetting about it is a bad idea.

Comment: @NotACleverMan Well right about the android thing and I accept the downvote. I knew it was an android question and answered for it but somehow mistyped all 'phone' with 'iphone'...:(..Edited the answer

Comment: But I had to clarify that I never said that OP should forget about correcting the cause of heat..What I said was that a general user will sometime misunderstand that heat is generated when the app is not running, when actually happened was phone got heated when app is last ran and the heat failed to cool off. Simply I just said to OP, **forget about your app causing heat when not running, make sure app is not heating up phone when running.**

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't really get that from your answer. I don't think you should say "forget about it" but instead say "Check to see if the problem is being caused this way FIRST". I do agree that some users may be mistaking the phone not cooling down fast enough, as it heating while the app isn't running, however, if many users are reporting the same thing it may be a legitimate issue.

Comment: is users say right the device is heat up even they do not run your app, then you can test it own ,for example install this on ten devices and checked is they heat up, if yes then check after uninstalling app. you will get the rght answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can cause a device to warm up is when you have a Service running in background and have it working on some real heavy loops or calculations...

And as I saw in your post, is not your case..